# How to set onHover event on angular-calendar events?

Tags: javascript, angular, calendar, angular-calendar

I am using a calendar module for my angular project: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar

I was able to set onClick events (show a modal) in a day inside the calendar, but I want to show the modal when I hover the day.

```html
<mwl-calendar-month-view 
  *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month" 
  [viewDate]="viewDate"
  [events]="events" 
  [refresh]="refresh" 
  [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
  (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)" 
  (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event) "
  [cellTemplate]="customCellTemplate" 
  (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
>
</mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

How could I set an **onHover** event, which is called when the user hover the event (day in the calendar)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseenter` in place of your mouse click.

```html
<div (mouseenter)="openDatePicker()">Hover Me</div>
```

There is also a `mouseleave` that you can use as well.